# Console app not parsing correctly args with white spaces

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, command-line-arguments

I've created a .NET console application that gets some command line arguments.

When I pass args with white spaces, I use quotes to embrace these arguments so that they are not splitted by cmd:

```
C:\MyAppDir> MyApp argument1 "argument 2" "the third argument"
```

If I execute the app in Windows XP it works fine: it gets 3 arguments:

- argument1
- argument 2
- the third argument

However, if i execute it in Windows Server 2008 it seems to ignore quotes: it gets 6 arguments:

- argument1
- "argument
- 2"
- "the
- third
- argument"

Any ideas why?

NOTE: I printed arguments just when Main starts execution using this code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Command line arguments:");
foreach (string arg in args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("# " + arg);
}
```

Comment: are you doing some sort of parsing with the args?

Comment: are you perhaps reading a \ which might be escaping a " ? also, are you sure the character you are typing is indeed the double quote " ? maybe it's a character that looks like it. i know my greek language settings produce a " but it's not read that way.

Comment: Grand @ericosg!  That was it, I don't know why, but quotes seemed to be something different (???).  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure the character you are typing is indeed the double quote ".

Maybe it's a character that looks like it.

I know my Greek language settings produce a " but it's not read that way.

Comment: posted as an answer so you can ensure you close it, rather than just a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Please Try it.

C:\MyAppDir> MyApp argument1 \"argument 2\" \"the third argument\"

Answer (score 0):

You can try, put each arguments between Quota"" and in the paths put double backslash for example like that:

generadorPlantillasPDF.exe "C:\GDI\desarrollos\celula canales\proyectos\Progreso\curso xml\" generadorprogreso.xml C:\Temp\ BVI "C:\GDI\desarrollos\celula canales\proyectos\Progreso\plantilla\" "C:\GDI\desarrollos\celula canales\proyectos\Progreso\" "Formulario Progreso Version 2.0.docx" C:\Temp\