# Command line arguments, paths with spaces, parsing incorrectly

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I have an issue that's nearly identical to the one outlined here ([Console app not parsing correctly args with white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548777/console-app-not-parsing-correctly-args-with-white-spaces)) but that answer has no bearing on my situation.

I'm receiving arguments to my simple program that are paths and path+filenames with potentially lots of spaces in them. What's happening is that spaces in the paths are generating many more arguments than I actually have. I was manually reconstructing what I needed by passing through the args array, but I discovered today that if the filename has two spaces my method won't work, and I can't know that in the program to fix it.

> Upload "\somesrv\Data\cust\99999_Test4\Working\" "\somesrv\Data\cust\99999_Test4\Working\99999_Test4-GUAST - Buyers List PA  11 15 14_112514_101753 AM_Sht=And stuff_Automation\99999_Test4-GUAST - Buyers List PA  11 15 14_112514_101753 AM_Sht=And stuff_Automation.zip"

So in the case of that set of arguments I get an args[] with 21 elements. Given that there's a pair of spaces at one point I have no hope of correcting this.

Is there anything I can do to make sure that the paths come through in tact? On the giving or receiving end is fine, as I'm in control of both, but not the paths/filenames themselves.

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //args 0 = Switch value
    //args 1 = Working Directory
    //args 2 = Mail.dat zip file

    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }

    string maildatName = args[1].Substring(args[1].IndexOf("Working")+8, args[1].Length - (args[1].IndexOf("Working")+8)) + " ";

    for (int x = 2; x < args.Length; x++)
    {
        maildatName += args[x];
        maildatName += " ";
    }

    args[1] = args[1].Substring(0, args[1].IndexOf("Working") + 7);
    maildatName = maildatName.Trim();
}
```

Comment: This seems like a fantastic place to use a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by the `\"` at the end of your first argument.

If you remove the trailing slash or add an extra slash before the quote then you will get two arguments.  The quote is being escaped and is considered part of the first argument until it hits the next quote 2 characters later.  After that you are no longer inside of a quote and thus each space results in another argument added to the `args` array.

This is caused by the fact that .Net uses `CommandLineToArgvW` to process command line arguments and the rules it uses to handle escaping of characters.

Jon Galloway has a [writeup](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/_5B002E00_NET-Gotcha_5D00_-Commandline-args-ending-in-_5C002200_-are-subject-to-CommandLineToArgvW-whackiness) on this

To quote:

> CommandLineToArgvW has a special interpretation of backslash characters when they are followed by a quotation mark character ("),
>   as follows:
>
> - 2n backslashes followed by a quotation mark produce n backslashes followed by a quotation mark.
> - (2n) + 1 backslashes followed by a quotation mark again produce n backslashes followed by a quotation mark.
> - n backslashes not followed by a quotation mark simply produce n backslashes.

Comment: Ah! Now that makes me feel a bit less insane. Thanks for the detail and the blog link. I tested with the extra \ at the end of the troublesome path and indeed got the results I was after.

In order to dodge the issue with the need to only make changes in one place I implemented a solution similar to what jac suggested, but with a bit more mechanics in the hope for future-proofing.

Answer (score 0):

It is because youre slash here `Working\"`, when you add another slash it works correctly I believe
 so make It `<snip>...Working\\"`

edit: I just tested it myself, with a double `\\` you get 3 items :)

[image]

Also see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/twistylittlepassagesallalike/archive/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-arguments-the-wrong-way.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the additional link. That definitely helped me understand what was happening and how to avoid such troubles in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Join the args into a string again, then Split that string on the double quote character.

```
string parms = String.Join(" ", args);
string[] arguments = parms.Split('\"');
...
```

BTW: This is a work around for the problem John Koerner has explained.